# Add and delete records with ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, web

I am using emberjs for mvc in client side, I'm facing a problem when I would like to delete a record et create another with the same Id of the deleted one.

It shows me this error

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The id 2
>   has already been used with another record of type Client.Componant.

I tried `destroyRecord()` and `store.unloadRecord(...)` but it seems like the store still have the record which supposed deleted in his cache or some thing like that.

Any HELP please !!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trying reading through http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/creating-and-deleting-records/ for help.

Comment: I already saw it, that shows how to create and delete not more, my question is to create with an id of deleted record, that's my problem. The documentation of emberjs is very poor, normally we should not face such a problem.